# Simpler Security Cameras

Tags: surveillance-cameras

i have several older Foscams that work great, but are getting old and like to replace them.  I do NOT want to rely on an app, or cloud storage.  these cameras have a built in web-server that has the controls for sound/motion detection and can send via email pictures of an event.

I can't seem to find a camera that doesn't want to see cloud storage and "there is an app for that".

Comment: Hi Barry, not sure the *Internet of Things Stack Exchange* is the right place to ask then. Though IoT is always a bit fuzzy to define, but a camera that sends an email on an event is mostly not included.

Comment: perhaps you should ask at [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)? Good question, though; I would be interested to hear the answer. As an alternative, could you use a Raspberry Pi plus camera?

Comment: I am also interested, but this is off topic, not least because vendors come and go quite fast in this area. Motion detection is a bit CPU heavy, ucam 247 works, but isn't cheap or stable.

Answer (score 2):

While the Wyze cams ship with all the cloud crap, they also provide firmware that appears to limit the camera to your local LAN, providing RTSP to the client of your choice. They're cheap, attractive, and have good reviews. 
Disclaimer: I intend to get one or two and test them for 'leakage' off the LAN, but haven't yet, soo ... grain of salt :)

[Wyze RTSP](https://support.wyzecam.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026245231-Wyze-Cam-RTSP)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ESP32-CAM-WiFi-WiFi-Module-ESP32-serial-to-WiFi-ESP32-CAM-Development-Board-5V-Bluetooth-with/32947577882.html). It's an ESP32, which has both BlueTooth and Wifi, and this one has a built in camera.

I bought a few last week and am awaiting delivery. This one cost $7.45, but I think mine were slightly cheaper $6.XX.

> I can't seem to find a camera that doesn't want to see cloud storage 
>   This one doesn't
>
> and "there is an app for that"...
>   ... and can send via email pictures of an event

Alas, you have to provide the app. Code your own, or ask us at [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

I plan on using a Raspberry Pi Zero W as a central server for the cameras, but if you can code it would be simple enough to have the ESP32 send email.

[image]

Comment: I am going with the Reolink C2 Pro.  I has an app, but not needed.  the only difficult thing to do is set up port forwarding, and my ATT router picked up the device, although I had to enable the port forward.

I'm just learning the features, had to upgrade the firmware twice to work properly on Ubuntu Firefox.  Also I DO think this is an IOT.  you can write scripts for this device to perform something (like turn on alarms) and sending email or pushing can be to another device, such as turning all the IOT lites on in the house and locking the refrigerator!